# Is it appropriate or acceptable to thank a professor for their dissenting public opinion?

Tags: etiquette, communication

This is a question mainly in case I haven't foreseen any potential repercussions.

The pandemic is a contentious issue, and a particular academic in my country has been outspoken with the same view as me. I'm currently a PhD student, and would just like to send an e-mail in support to said academic, especially considering that I imagine they would be the victim of many negative and/or abusive communications, again given the contentious nature of the topic.

Their field is also an application of mine, so I would be interested in discussing some of their research in that vein.

Comment: Does their opinion interfere with their scientific work or is it separate and private opinion?

Comment: What does this have to do with academia?

Comment: Unless s/he is one of those talking to the public in TV like they are speaking to a colleague during coffee break, go ahead. But I don't see why this question relates to Academia SE.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  Telling someone you appreciate their taking a public stand you agree with, thanking them for it, is always appropriate and appreciated, especially when you suspect they've taken some heat for doing so.

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason that you should be worried about sending your support note to the professor. This happens all the time. People more often send disagreeable, if not nasty notes to people they do not agree with. This may be your introduction to the professor by  way of explaining your work, etc.